# Create an "one time clickable" button for a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, dom-events

I want to create an "one-time clickable" button to launch my website... Would you please help me with this? I tried almost like everything in Stack Overflow, but nothing could solve this thing.

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: What framework are you using to animate the button? Plain javascript, jquery, react? Please add some code.

Answer (score 1):

**1) jQuery one() method**

If you’re using jQuery, there’s a little-known **one()** event binding method which implements one-time events.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").one("click", function(){
    alert("You'll only see this once!");
  });
});
```

HTML :-

```
<button>click me</button>
```

**2) JavaScript**
If you’re using raw JavaScript, any handler function can remove itself using a single line of code:

```
document.getElementById("myelement").addEventListener("click", handler);

// handler function
function handler(e) {
    // remove this handler
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

    alert("You'll only see this once!");
}
```